# v8 release mode linker error with winsock

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, winsock, v8, release-mode

This subject became a side subject after I accepted an answer for my last question, so I will put it here as a separate topic for neatness, and I believe this will make it more useful for others.

I am working on MS visual studio 2005.

I am building a project using v8 in release mode, and am receiving a linker error that is related to winsock even though the winsock libraries are already in my additional dependencies.

My additional dependencies list is the same for both release and debug mode. It works perfectly in debug mode, and I am getting the linker errors only in release mode.

here is my additional dependencies string:

```
Ws2_32.lib wininet.lib rasapi32.lib iphlpapi.lib Psapi.lib winmm.lib wsock32.lib msvcrt.lib $(SolutionDir)\external_libs\debug\v8.lib $(SolutionDir)external_libs\release\v8_base.lib $(SolutionDir)external_libs\release\v8_snapshot.lib
```

Thanks a lot for any possible help.

**Update:**

I reduced the dependencies to:

```
Ws2_32.lib Psapi.lib winmm.lib msvcrt.lib $(SolutionDir)\external_libs\release\v8.lib $(SolutionDir)external_libs\release\v8_base.lib
```

and still get unresolved externals:

```
1>v8_base.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__freeaddrinfo@4
1>v8_base.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__getaddrinfo@16
1>v8_base.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __set_abort_behavior
```

Comment: ...the error message would be good. Considering if you have `ws2_32` in there it's not going to be `Unresolved External`.

Answer (score 0):

You have paths to both debug and release folders in your dependency list. Try replacing those with `$(Configuration)`.

Comment: I reduced the dependeincies to: Ws2_32.lib Psapi.lib winmm.lib msvcrt.lib $(SolutionDir)\external_libs\release\v8.lib $(SolutionDir)external_libs\release\v8_base.lib, and still get unresolved externals: 1>v8_base.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__freeaddrinfo@4
1>v8_base.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__getaddrinfo@16
1>v8_base.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __set_abort_behavior
...